# webView and 'timeout'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have  question, in my application I need to have a connection and a webview to display the web content.
The problem is that I have a username and a password which need to be right in order to get a connection. Now I want to have an alert that comes up if the username is wrong. The

```
 - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

does not work for this, because if the username or the password is wrong it will continue loading (even though it won't display anything).

Is there a possibilty to 'tell' webview to set a time interval and then display an alert?

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Is this password requirement enforced by the server? If so, the response should contain the appropriate error for you to process and display the appropriate error to app users.

Comment: no, the password is sent to the server like this:
http://username:password@website.com
and if i enter a wrong username/password on my mac web browser he asks me do reenter both. this doesn't work for the iphone so i wanted to have something like a 'timer'

Answer (score 0):

If you're authenticating with your server via HTTP authentication (per your comment above) then I would do this differently. When the user enters their username/pwd, make a request to any page (something lightweight) using `NSURLConnection`. If the username/password are incorrect you can handle the failures in the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods and prompt your user for a new username/password.

You can also do this with the iOS 5 version of `NSURLConnection` instead of the delegate methods but the docs aren't very good.

When this first request succeeds then load the web view.

**EDIT: added example of using NSURLConnection to check if HTTP auth succeeds**

Ok, here's a simple example. You can make this better by allowing `NSURLConnection` to load your intended request and if it succeeds load the response data into the `webView` vs initiating a new request. Read the URL Loading System docs to learn more about how to use `NSURLConnection`.

In your `webView` delegate, initiate an `NSURLConnection` with a request to the same domain as the `webView` request with the user credentials as follows:

```
- (void)performHTTPAuthRequest
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%@@test.starsightings.com", username, password]]];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

// if the request succeeds, credentials must be good so load the webView
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // request completed successfully so username/password must be good
    [self.webView loadRequest:theRequest];
}

// ignore the failure
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}

// if we get an auth challenge, the credentials are bad so cancel the request and alert the user
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    // alert user that username/pwd is invalid
}
```

Comment: okay, so can you explain me how to do it? because I don't understand it :(